# What's it called when someone imposes his own beliefs and ideas on someone else?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

There's a concept which I am not yet familiar with. 
When someone forces his own ideology, beliefs and thoughts on someone else and not allow them to think for themselves?

For example: when a head chairman state his opinion about a political candidate and makes everyone else in the department approve of him and refuse anyone else to belief anything but what they said.

Comment: Is this meant to include state-sponsored religion?

Comment: Related, almost a duplicate of: [*Is there a word or phrase meaning to plant my idea in someone else’s mind?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186670/is-there-a-word-or-phrase-meaning-to-plant-my-idea-in-someone-else-s-mind) and also related [*What is less harsh than “brainwashing”?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292736/what-is-less-harsh-than-brainwashing)

Comment: *Indoctrinate* comes close. *Proselytise* is a bit more distant, lacking force.

Comment: I would describe the example you give as _a fool surrounded by yes-men_.

Comment: A tyrant. A despot.

Comment: Are you looking for a verb, or a noun? In other words, do you want to describe the head chairman in your example, or do you want to describe his actions? An example sentence or two where you would use the word, with ___ where the word would go, will help us give you better answers. (This is generally needed for single word requests.)

Comment: The person who does that, and the system that allows him to do that, is *authoritarian*.  The verb in your title, *impose*, fits perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The person in question is ***domineering***.

ODO:

> **[domineer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/domineer)**
>   *VERB*
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>   *usually as adjective **domineering***
>   **Assert one's will over another in an arrogant way**:
>   ‘Cathy had been a martyr to her gruff,
>   domineering husband’
>
> ‘Or is it that they are so controlling and domineering that we don't
>   know how to talk about anything else?’

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for "**opinion-maker**"?

> - a person whose opinion influences the opinions of many other people -  [**MW**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opinion%20maker)

An opinion maker doesn't force his opinion on others, though. He needn't do it. He is usually so admired and respected by a certain group that whatever he says is taken for granted.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word "**impose**", as you used it in the title of the question is perfect for the meaning you're trying to convey.

"The chairman was determined to impose his view of the issue on the rest of the committee."

The term is more commonly used of religious belief. For example (from an English national newspaper)

"Whether you're religious or secular, imposing your views on others is foolish"
(https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2012/apr/20/deborah-orr-imposing-views-religious-secular)

Dictionary Definition :  to establish or apply by authority

(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impose)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the answer to make it clear that I think that the word he's used in the title is actually the one he's looking for.

Comment: I agree! // Can you add a definition and a link?  And -- footnotes are sophisticated, but if you put a link in a footnote, people are liable to miss it.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps ***officious***:

> Your chairman is an officious ideologue.

From [Oxford Dictionaries](//en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/officious):

> **officious**
>
> 1. assertive of authority in an annoyingly domineering way, especially with regard to petty or trivial matters.
>
>    *‘a policeman came to move them on, an officious, spiteful man’*
>
>    1. intrusively enthusiastic in offering help or advice; interfering.
>
>       *‘an officious bystander’*
>
>       synonyms: **self-important**, bumptious, self-assertive, overbearing, overzealous, domineering, opinionated, interfering, intrusive, meddlesome, meddling

Answer (score -1):

In part, the term "Imprinting" came to mind, but that doesn't seem right. to Indoctrinate? or *forcibly* indoctrinate?