# What is called when someone tries to change another into their ideal?

Tags: vocabulary

[This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/362984) question did not give me the answer I am looking for.

Recently, I watched an episode of an anime called 'Jaku-chara Tomozaki-kun' and seeing how the female lead was acting towards the male lead made me uncomfortable. From the first episode, she is seen imposing her ideals on him. I went on to a related site and I found out that she is trying to turn him into her ideal man. What I wanted to know is that what this behaviour is called is there a word for it? Something that came to mind was 'Indoctrination' but it didn't feel quite right so I wanted to ask here.

Comment: I think it is important to note that "turning someone into your ideal man" is a different usage of the word "ideal" than then one meaning "strongly held belief", and that your "ideal mate" might not even hold the same ideals as you... there is certainly overlap, though.  This might confuse answers to this question.

Comment: While I'm here, though, "convince of", "impose ideals on", "convert (to the belief of)"... inculcate (rarely)... you might look up "apologetics" (also a bit rare)... there are a few ways we might say it figuratively, like 'bashing' or 'battering' someone, or someone's head in, with whatever idea.  "propagandize"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Mould = to try to change or influence someone
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mould)

A good example is in P G Wodehouse’s novel *Jeeves takes Charge* when Aunt Agatha refers to a strong-willed prospective wife for the rather vapid Bertie Wooster:

> Aunt Agatha: She will mould you!
>
> Bertie: I don't want to be moulded. I'm not a jelly.
>
> Aunt Agatha: That is a matter of opinion
>
> [Elizaratcliffe](http://jeevesandwooster.eliseratcliffe.co.uk/quotes/14/)

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't see why you've rejected *indoctrination*, which to me is a pretty good choice in the given context, I suggest **brainwashing.**

> a forcible indoctrination to induce someone to give up basic political, social, or religious beliefs and attitudes and to accept contrasting regimented ideas.

[Merriam-Webster]